# result from a template function unexpected

Tags: c++

this code doesn't give me the expected result! how is that?

```
template<typename T, std::enable_if_t < std::is_arithmetic_v<T>,bool> =true>
auto avr(T t)
{
    return t;
}
template<typename T,class ... C, std::enable_if_t<(std::is_arithmetic_v<T> &&...&& std::is_arithmetic_v<C>), bool> =true>
auto avr(T t,C...c)
{
    return (t + avr(c...)) / (sizeof...(c)+1);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout<<avr(1,5,3,7);

    return 0;
}
```

can someone explain how to resolve that?

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: my expected result is 4

Comment: Please give [mvce]. What is is_arithmetic_v

Comment: mvce?
to say if the T and C are both arithmetic

Comment: You are dividing each time by sizeof, so first you are dividing by 4 then by 3 then by 2

Answer (score 1):

Because each time you divide by the `sizeof`, not just the first one, instead you should do something like this:

```
template<class ... C, std::enable_if_t<(...&& std::is_arithmetic_v<C>), bool> =true>
auto sum(C...c)
{
    return (c + ...);
}
template<typename T,class ... C, std::enable_if_t<(std::is_arithmetic_v<T> &&...&& std::is_arithmetic_v<C>), bool> =true>
auto avr(T t,C...c)
{
    return (t + sum(c...)) / (sizeof...(c)+1);
}
```

and so first sum the numbers, and then divide (only one time)

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that you wanted to use an [incremental mean](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/106720/450342) computation.

In that case there are two problems:

**First:** you need to multiply by `sizeof...(c)` for each update

```
auto
avr(T t, C... c)
{
  return (t + sizeof...(c)*avr(c...)) / (sizeof...(c) + 1);
}
```

**Second:** you must use `avr(1., 5., 3., 7.)` otherwise, with `avr(1, 5, 3, 7)`, you use integer arithmetic (`T,C...=int`) and get a wrong result

```
int
main()
{
  std::cout << avr(1., 5., 3., 7.);

  return 0;
}
```

With these two modifications you get your expected result: `4`

---

**Update**: if you wanted to use the classical formula: mean = sum / n, see other answers. However you still have to use real arithmetic for the last division.

Comment: actually to get 4 you don't need floating point operation, it's just 16/4, however it's a good point if this was just "by case", and so if it was 15/4 it returns the wrong average

Comment: why the program doesn't compile on MSVS 2019?

Comment: it's c++17, I compile it with g++ or clang++. I have no access to MSVS2019

Comment: @Berto99 I do agree, the problem is that I do not know if Ope intial goal was to use an  "incremental" formula or not... Anyway if Ope wants  a procedure that returns the correct mean in all cases he needs real arithmetic at least for the last step sum/n

Comment: yes sure, but maybe is better to put a `*1.` inside the `avr ` division, in order to not be dependent to the user input in that case

Comment: @Berto99, yes I do agree with you

Comment: ```Error C2672 'avr': no matching overloaded function found C++Features```
, ```Error C2783 'auto avr(T,C...)': could not deduce template argument for '__formal'```
```Error C2780 'auto avr(T)': expects 1 arguments - 3 provided```

Comment: @Ope, thanks for the feedback. Unfortunately I cannot help here as I am under Linux. All I can say is that I think my solution is valid/regular C++17 and it compiles with g++ and clang++